# How to use standalone Gutenberg (block editor) instance on any my own admin page in WordPress

Tags: customization, pages, block-editor

Can any WP expert please help to manage this issue. I want to use the block editor, absolutely the same as in post editing page, but use it in my own admin page within WordPress CMS. Probably there should be any easy enough solution to include some wp scripts, launch wp functions and add any other dependencies? What I managed to have done is to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@automattic/isolated-block-editor over gutenberg package and with some problems it works, but also I want to include it into some meta-boxes on post-edit page (for input content for some additional optional blocks for particular posts, never mind), but when i try to do this error appears: "Store "core/interface" is already registered." and "You tried to opt-in to unstable APIs as module "@wordpress/edit-post" which is already registered." that is probably cause of isolated-block-editor over gutenberg and native wp gutenberg editor, that do the same registration... And I thought is there probably way to create another instance of WP Gutenberg editor that is located in wp.blockEditor and other components in wp global object, but how correctly is it can be performed. Is it really possible that such task doesn't appear frequently enough to solve it (((

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress Development SE. Your question is coming along nicely but could use a few edits. Could you try to break it up into a few paragraphs so that it does not look like a wall of text? You may also wish to consider sharing the code where the problem is. The less guessing WP Devs need to do, the more they are likely to offer you a brilliant answer. If in doubt, take a look at a few questions with answers as examples of how to write a great question.